# Can I turn off MacBook Pro startup noise from Windows?

Tags: macbook, macbook-pro

I have been using my MacBook Pro at work recently. It only has Windows and Linux on it (no OS X).  The problem it the really LOUD startup sound that Apple forces you to have.

I work in a cubicle and it really sucks every time I have to restart my computer: not only is it loud, but it's embarrassing. Is there any way I can mute this sound from Windows?

Comment: Could you hold your thumbs/palms over the speaker ports? Does plugging headphones in work? (I don't have a MacBook, so I'm not sure how feasible the first is nor whether the second works at all)

Answer (score 1):

The chime is set in PRAM, so simply put, no.

The output device is always automatically set to external speakers, so having headphones in shouldn't fix your problem.

The only solution I know of is muting your sound before shutdown, because that **isn't** reset.

I know, not the answer you were looking for; there isn't even a fix if you had OS X still installed. :\

Comment: But muting sound in Windows or Linux doesn't work.  It has to be muted in Mac.

Comment: I assume you erased the OS X partition.

A simple, but time consuming fix, is to reinstall OS X, mute sound, shutdown, remove OS X.

Comment: Not so simple because the rest of my HDD is full with other non apple partitions.

Comment: a >=8GB USB stick?